# ruby : when to use 'load' to load file instead of 'require'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i know the basic difference between load and require statement. `load` loads the file multiple time even if it is already loaded and `require` loads the file only once.

i want to know when to use `load` statement over `require` statement. if possible then please explain with small example.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `load` re-loads the file, even if it is already loaded; whereas `require` loads the file only once.

As such, you should almost always (for performance reasons) use `require` instead of `load`.

Using `load` can be useful if the file frequently changes state - although this is a rare thing to happen.

Typically, `load` is geared more to implementing customized runners for Ruby code than to simply loading the classes and modules in your projects - for example, it's often used by `Capistrano`. Or another common use is when developing/debugging a project with an open console, you can use: `load 'filename_i_just_edited'` to refresh to code state, rather than re-starting the console.